# Create a Setup and Deployment Project in windows without .net support

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, setup-project

I have got a vc++ project and for that I have created .exe and .lib.
Now, I am trying to create a set up project for this.
I am following the instructions given on this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317(v=vs.90).aspx

under the heading: Procedures for deploying Visual C++ library DLLs as private assemblies

I am removing mfcm90.dll, mfcm90u.dll, and msvcm90.dll from my set up project and my .exe has been built with "No Common Language Runtime support" option.

I am making a release build of set up project.
Now, when I try to install this project on a windows machine, which does not have any visual studio installed, it asks for installation of .NET and even that installation is failing.
How can I create a set up project without requiring .NET dependency.

Thanks,
sg

Comment: Who asks for .NET Framework and how? Is it an error message? Is the .NET Framework installer launched? Can you give us more details?

Comment: When I try to run setup.exe on a windows machine that does not have Visual studio or .net framework installed, I get a license agreement to install .Net framework. This is one thing that I don't want. Even if I accept agreement, I get the error "An error occurred while downloading the required file". My application is not based on .Net, so I don't want it be installed at all

Comment: Yes, >NET framework installer is launched. I don't want it to be launched in first place. Even, if I accept the license agreement, it fails to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .NET Framework installer is launched during install only if you added it as a prerequisite. You can change prerequisites by clicking the "Prerequisites..." button in your setup project Properties pane.

For your project you should make sure that no .NET Framework prerequisite is checked.

Comment: Hi,I have unchecked .NET Framework prerequisite. Now, I am not getting the .NET framework installer but a message saying that "this set up requires >net framework version 3.5. Please install it and run set up again. It can be downloaded from web. Would u like to do it now" Even on clicking yes, it takes me to some dead link on microsoft website

Comment: Are you launching the EXE or the MSI? Try the MSI. Also, does your setup project use any custom actions? Please make sure that nothing in your setup project requires .NET Framework.

Comment: I am getting the same message on launching both setup and msi file. I have checked everywhere, I can't find any mention of .NET anywhere. I am not sure what is going wrong and I am totally new to this.

Comment: Hi,Are there any suggestions for me?

Comment: I had not realized that internet was not working on my PC, tahts why it was not able to download .Net. It can download >net and proceed with the installation of the application smoothly, only problem being that I don't want it to install .Net.

Comment: It seems like the prerequisite is still active. I'm not sure what configuration you are using. If you want, I can take a look at your setup project.

Comment: Yeah, that would be great. But, Can you please suggest how should I make it available. Shall I zip it and attach here?

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the .sln file here: http://cid-fdc8cf0b990fdcd8.office.live.com/browse.aspx/Setup%20Project

Comment: The solution is just a container. The setup project contains your package configuration. You can send it by email to cosmin at setupanddeployment dot com.

Comment: sent it. Please have a look at it whenever its convenient for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, my answer is a bit late, but may be it will be useful for someone else.

Right mouse click on the your deployment project -> View -> Launch condition -> delete .NET condition from "Requirement" tree.